# How to cleanly handle dependencies in ament?

Tags: ros, ros2, ament, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I build a library to be used by other ROS 2 developers, what is the way to make it easy to use for downstream packages?

In modern CMake one answer should be exporting targets. This would then allow downstream packages to easily use that target via e.g. `find_package(some_dependency REQUIRED)` and `target_link_libraries(new_target [PUBLIC | PRIVATE | INTERFACE] some_dependency::some_dependency)` and if the author of `some_dependency` has done things right, that's all I have to do as the author of `my_target`.

Ament_cmake provides help for the exporting mechanism using `install(TARGETS my_dependency EXPORT some_dependency ...)` and `ament_export_interface(some_dependency)` (which does the heavy lifting if I'm right). Now if `some_dependency` itself depends on `some_other_dependency`, it seems that this dependency must have been added to `ament_export_dependencies()` for the target `some_dependency` even if it is not used in any header and could be linked privately. Otherwise I would have to `find_package(some_other_dependency)` in the build of `new_target`, which is wrong. This might be an artifact of the problem that it seems impossible to use `target_link_libraries` together with keywords `PUBLIC | PRIVATE | INTERFACE` as they are not used internally in ament (at least that's what CMake tells me).

However, there is also `ament_target_dependencies()` and `ament_export_dependencies()` and they seem to provide another way of handling dependencies: If I have a ROS 2 package where the export target (if it exists) does not have the same name as the target (then, for some reason, it seems I have to use `target_link_libraries`, see below for an example), I can just use `ament_target_dependencies(new_target some_dependency)`. If the dependency is used in a header and therefore needs to be linked publicly/by interface, I additionally have to add `ament_export_dependency(some_dependency)` (in contrast to how I have to use it with exported targets, see above).

**What's the preferred way of doing things and how to do this way right?**

Some real world examples:

- Currently, rosbag2 relies entirely on the second mechanism. See https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/blob/master/rosbag2/CMakeLists.txt for an example (no `target_link_libraries`, no EXPORT, etc.)
- RViz relies on a mix of using targets and not (see for instance https://github.com/ros2/rviz/blob/42e3c4b47bc6acd90ed690b884bcc385555c382c/rviz_rendering/CMakeLists.txt#L104, but the CMakeLists should be cleaned up...).
- When trying to clean this up I found: For the `resource_retriever`, I have to use `target_link_libraries`, for `ament_index_cpp`, I can also use `ament_target_dependencies`. The only difference between the two is that the name of the EXPORT target in `ament_index_cpp` is different from the target, while it is the same for `resource_retriever` (see https://github.com/ros/resource_retriever/blob/ros2/resource_retriever/CMakeLists.txt#L50 vs https://github.com/ament/ament_index/blob/2ae14036e2c4f9db6fce022a47e300f71c47ea64/ament_index_cpp/CMakeLists.txt#L59)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305991/how-to-cleanly-handle-dependencies-in-ament?/) by [Martin-Idel](https://answers.ros.org/users/38066/martin-idel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-10-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ament_cmake_*` offers two different approaches to export dependencies:

- The "classic" CMake approach to export CMake variables like `<pkgname>_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, `<pkgname>_LIBRARIES`, etc.

  Related functions are `ament_cmake_export_definitions`, `ament_cmake_export_dependencies`, `ament_cmake_export_include_directories`, `ament_cmake_export_libraries`. Helper functions like `ament_target_dependencies` make it easier to use the CMake variables and add "all" of them to a given target.
- The "modern" CMake approach to export targets.

  The function `ament_cmake_export_interfaces` does the "heavy lifting" as you mentioned.

A package can decide to use either approach (or both) and downstream packages can use available information accordingly.

Atm almost all ROS 2 packages use the classic approach. The desire / goal would be to use the latter approach everywhere since it provides a cleaner and more precise way (hence it is the modern version).

The the latter approach isn't used much (I am only aware of [ament_index_cpp](https://github.com/ament/ament_index/blob/master/ament_index_cpp/CMakeLists.txt)) it might be that the API provided isn't sufficient yet. It seems a function like `ament_export_dependency` but for the exported target case is missing.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [strike_eagle_iii](https://answers.ros.org/users/38642/strike_eagle_iii/) on 2022-05-31**:
For anyone that finds this answer I just want to throw out there that `ament_cmake_export_interfaces` appears to now be deprecated and is replaced by `ament_cmake_export_targets` and `ament_cmake_export_dependencies`: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Ament-CMake-Documentation.html

I really hope the classical cmake approach gets deprecated altogether (if it's not already) as the modern target based approach is significantly cleaner / easier to use / better in pretty much every way.